# Strange merge/rebase result in GIT

Tags: git, date, merge

guys! I migrated our project from Mercurial to GIT recently, all things works well and we like it more than Mercurial. There is only one thing that confused us.

scenery 1:
Sometims, one of our programmers may change his system date because of self-testing. It's a big he forgot to change the system date back when he finished the task. Then, commit, rebase, push, everthing is ok( if he has changed his system date later ).
At the same time, another programmer has made some changes, the poor guy start to commit, and found the first guy's commit, so he pull it down. Now, it's time to merge or rebase. BOOM!!!  Both actions failed, and his own commit's parent has changed, his parent is nobody.

scenery 2:
A evil programmer who has changed his system date later and pushed his changes with incorrect system date. Now, I have made some changes and committed. I'm going to push my commit: pull, rebase...BOOM!!! Hey where is my damn commit's parent? of course the rebase action failed.

scenery 3:
............

whether change the system date earlier or later, the rebase or merge failed, and some commit's parent is gone. It's not easy to remember to change your system date back if you changed the system date.

I don't think there is a way to remind us: have you changed your system date? In most of time, we dont care about the commit time, can we just ignore the commit date while merge or rebase?

Comment: What is the error message showed by the git command in those situations?

Comment: I'm sorry! I did more digs. everything works well in GIT actually. The real issue is the SourceTree draw the log incorrectly. I'm going to create a test repo and commit a but to SoureTree's team.